# JDK 8-java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sunw.io.Serializable

Tags: java

When I try to run my java class I am getting below error message but same is working fine in JDK 1.7.

Newly I have installed JDK 8 after that I am getting below Error. How to solve this problem?

```
Some related files cannot be found :
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sunw/io/Serializable
```

I am loading my class file using

```
Class inv = Class.forName(ClassName);
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sunw.io.Serializable
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Post the stack trace and the relevant code. Question is incomprehensible and unanswerable without it.

Comment: Some related files cannot be found :java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sunw/io/Serializable. This is only happening when i use JDK 8

Comment: We can read what you already posted. You don't need to post it twice. What we can't read is the part you didn't post. The part I asked for. The stack trace and the relevant code. -1

Comment: i am loading my class file using 

Class inv = Class.forName(ClassName);

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sunw.io.Serializable
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: So why are you attempting to load `sunw.io.Serializable`? And if you're not, what class *are* you attempting to load? and where is its definition? and how exactly do you expect anyone else to solve your problem for you when you omit basic information like this? and when you have to be asked for it two or three times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class `sunw.io.Serializable` is deprecated and hence shouldn't be used. It looks like JDK 8 has got rid of this, and hence not available for use at runtime.

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/api/sunw.io.Serializable.html

You need to use `java.io.Serializable` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your update. i need to change in my code where i have used sunw.io.Serializable

Comment: @Mahendiran You had Java Beans that were developed under JDK 1.0.2? You used an interface that is clearly marked **FOR BACKWARD COMPATIBILITY ONLY - DO NOT USE**?